# Finding closet div (in next column of a table) using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Finding closet div (in next column of a table) using jquery

```
     <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" minlen=5 tabindex=0/></td>
     <td><div></div></td>
```

And i tryed

```
    $("#username").next("div").html("hai");
```

Which is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write:

```
$("#username").closest("td").next().find("div").html("hai");
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466981/jquery-closest-not-working

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#username")
.parent()//td
.next()// next td
.find('div')//got the div, if you want the first use div:first
.html("hai");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8n9yx/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("#username").nextAll('div').first().html('hai')`

http://jsfiddle.net/gmDRM/91/

Comment: Did you check the fiddle I used? make sure you are using this after DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to add div in td. If you just want to populate next column of the same row use:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').html("hai");
```

if you need to put "hai" in  then just update the html as in

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').html("<div>hai</div>");
```