# jQuery closest(); not working

Tags: jquery, traversal, closest

I am trying to do make some text show when a text input is on focus, but the closest(); method doesn't seem to be working.

I have done a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U6Fwp/2/) for you to look at.

and here is the code also.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.validation-error').hide();
  $('.name-input').on("focus", function(){
   $(this).closest('.validation-error').show();
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<fieldset>
 <legend>User Details</legend>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td width="200">
     <label for="user"><span class="required-fields">*</span> User     Name</label>
    </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" id="user" class="name-input">
  </td>
  <td>
   <p class="validation-error">This field cannot be blank or less than 2 characters.</p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <label for="job_title"><span class="required-fields">*</span> Job Title</label></td>
   <td>
    <input type="text" id="job_title" class="name-input">
   </td>
   <td>
    <p class="validation-error">This field cannot be blank or less than 2 characters.</p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <label for="full_name">* Full Name</label>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="text" id="full_name" class="name-input">
  </td>
  <td>
   <p class="validation-error">This field cannot be blank or less than 2 characters.</p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
</fieldset>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `closest` is traversing the parents

Comment: What about checking the doc? http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: The `closest()` method doesn't work in IE / Edge. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=element-closest for supported browsers.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) finds the nearest parent element, `.validation-error` is not a parent of the `name-input` element. You need the `.validation-error` element which comes under the same `tr` as the input element

You need

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.validation-error').show();
```

or

```
$(this).closest('td').next().find('.validation-error').show();
```

Comment: I am using firefox v33.0. Whether closest is supported in this version

Answer (score 7):

Try my version [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U6Fwp/7/) although Arun P. Johny's answer is much better..

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find('.validation-error').show();
```